# Bootstrap 3 div over responsive image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have a full width `<div>` over an image, with text inside it, so that the text goes over the image itself. The grid and the image is responsive, and I can't get the `<div>` to be 100% of the grid.

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats" class="img-responsive portfolio_frontpage" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio_description">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Some random tekst blablabla</p> <span class="read_more"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats" class="img-responsive portfolio_frontpage" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio_description">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Some random tekst blablabla</p> <span class="read_more"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

As you can see, I want the `portfolio_desciption` to be over the image, fill the width of the grid `col-md-6` and have a white background.

Any suggestions on how my CSS should be composed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### tl;dr

Use `position: absolute;` with `top: 0;` on the `<div>` and don't forget to add `position: relative;` to their parent `<div>`s.

### Solution

```css
.portfolio_description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: white;
}
```

You also need a new class that you need to add to the parent elements of the `<div>`s that have the `.portfolio_description` class.

```css
.portfolio-block {
    position: relative;
}
```

### Explanation

The [MDN docs on `position: relative;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Absolute_positioning) states:

> The absolutely positioned element is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor (i.e., the nearest ancestor that is not static).

Also, the [MDN docs on `top`](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top) states:

> When position is set to absolute or fixed, the top property specifies the distance between the element's top edge and the top edge of its containing block.

So you need absolute positioning and because that is positioned relatively to the nearest non static ancestor, you need to make the parent elements relatively positioned, because that positioning is not static and will keep the element flow intact. Then just make sure the `top` property is set to `0` so there is no distance between the `<div>` and its containing block.

### Demo

In this example I used a semi-transparent background to prove that it is over the image.

```css
.portfolio_description {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.portfolio-block {
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 portfolio-block">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats" class="img-responsive portfolio_frontpage" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio_description">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Some random tekst blablabla</p> <span class="read_more"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6 portfolio-block">
            <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/300/cats" class="img-responsive portfolio_frontpage" alt="">
            <div class="portfolio_description">
                <h2>Heading</h2>
                <p>Some random tekst blablabla</p> <span class="read_more"></span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.row -->
</div>
<!-- /.container -->
```

Comment: I've already tried that, but thanks. The problem when i do that, is that it goes over the grid div, and looks like this: http://prntscr.com/2rgox3

Comment: Same problem here, did you manage to fix it? Demo looks nice only if there is white transparent bg .. there is overflow in the demo as well that can be seen if you change the colour to red or anything non white

Answer (score 1):

Got it working with the following CSS:

```
.portfolio_description {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use absolute positioning, [something like this](http://css-tricks.com/absolute-positioning-inside-relative-positioning/)

```
.col-md-6 {
    position: relative;
}

. portfolio_description{ 
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0px;
    hieght: 60px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a background image instead of inline images, adjust your code like below then add your image as a background image in your CSS, this gives you a lot more flexibility. this way you can absolutely position everything inside your #portfolio1 div

```
    <div class="col-md-6">
         <div id="portfolio1">
          <div class="portfolio_description">
            <h2>Heading</h2>
            <p>Some random tekst blablabla</p>
            <span class="read_more"></span>
          </div>
         </div> 
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

add the style=" padding-left: 0px ; padding-right: 0px;" in the col-md-6 or in whichever column div u are adding your image , the padding will fix the image entirely in the column without any before and after gap